# SQL query optimization for joining data from 4 tables using AND and OR conditions

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I have a SQL query to fetch data from 4 tables. But below query is fetching only 1 result more than 10,000 times and its taking long time to display. Can  anyone help me optimizing this query.

```
SELECT A0.* 
FROM Part A0, UnitValue A1, StringValue A2, PARTMASTER A3 
WHERE (A0.ida3reference=A3.id and A3.PartNumber LIKE 'RT-3294%') 
AND (((A1.idA6 = 3853762) AND (A1.value = 0.037099) 
AND (A1.idA4 = A0.id)) OR ((A2.idA6 = 19907282) AND (A2.value = '22') 
AND (A2.idA4 = A0.id)))
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged